# HTML 5 Shoutcast Stream not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, shoutcast

So, I have a fairly simple setup.

The site can be viewed [here](http://pixelperfectserver.tk/ipr/playertest.html)

And the bootstrap library for the icons is [here](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html)

```
<head>
    <style>
        #pButton{
            height:60px;
            width: 60px;
            border: none;
            background-size: 50% 50%;
            background-position: center;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min$
    <link href="css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/material-wfont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <audio id="music">
            <source src="http://listen.fillyradio.com:8006/;stream" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
        <div id="audioplayer">
            <button id="pButton" class="mdi-av-play-circle-outline" onclick"play()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // variable to store HTML5 audio element
        var music = document.getElementById('music');

        function play() {
            if (music.paused) {
                music.play();
                pButton.className = "";
                pButton.className = "mdi-av-pause-circle-outline";
            } else {
                music.pause();
                pButton.className = "";
                pButton.className = "mdi-av-play-circle-outline";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

My issue? The player works fine with controls enabled, but I want to be able to use custom controls, not the default browser controls.

The button clicks, but doesn't imitate audio or change icons like it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you see any errors in console? plus your link to load the bootstrap lib seems incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id="pButton" class="mdi-av-play-circle-outline" onclick"play()"></button>
```

you need = after your onclick

**new**

```
<button id="pButton" class="mdi-av-play-circle-outline" onclick="play()"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks! We miss the silliest things when we're blasting through code at late hours

Comment: happens to the best of us ;)